# Why does my Navbar interfere with my Stripe token creation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

**Issue:** My navbar, which works on javascript, is somehow interfering with my Stripe token creation.

Everything is fine when adding a stripe account id, but then i go to attach the bank account (external account) to the account id, it doesn't work.  I then realized when i would take away my navbar code, it would work...

**What in this code is interfering?:**

**Navbar code:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark fixed-top nav-color"> <a href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle" class="navbar-brand"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></a> <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample02" aria-controls="navbarsExample02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample02">
                <div class="navbar-header navbar-center">
                    <a class="navbar-brand center" id="navbar-center" href="/">Dashboard</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto ">
                    <!-- <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li> -->
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right dashboard-signout">

                <% if user_signed_in? || affiliate_signed_in? %>
                  <li class="nav-remove-1"><%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: "dashboard-signout" %>
                  </li>
                <% end %>
                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-md-0"> </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

**Here's the javascript for it:**

```
$(function(){
           $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
           });




           $(window).resize(function(e) {
             if($(window).width()<=992){
               $("#wrapper").removeClass("toggled");
             }else{
               $("#wrapper").addClass("toggled");
             }
           });
         });
```

With it, it won't work, without it, it works.

**Here's the stripe form in summary:**

```
<form action="/bank_accounts" method="POST" id="payment-form-1">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block btn-custom">Submit</button>
       <div class="outcome">
       <div class="error"></div>
       <div class="success">
                                        Success! Your Stripe token is <span class="token"></span>
       </div>
       </div>
</form>
```

**Javascript for the stripe bank acccount form:**

```
  var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_123456789');

  function setOutcome(result) {
  var successElement = document.querySelector('.success');
  var errorElement = document.querySelector('.error');
  successElement.classList.remove('visible');
  errorElement.classList.remove('visible');

  if (result.token) {
    // In this example, we're simply displaying the token
    successElement.querySelector('.token').textContent = result.token.id;
    successElement.classList.add('visible');

    // In a real integration, you'd submit the form with the token to your backend server
    var form = document.querySelector('form');
    form.querySelector('input[name="token"]').setAttribute('value', result.token.id);
    form.submit();

  } else {
    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    errorElement.classList.add('visible');
  }
}

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var bankAccountParams = {
    country: document.getElementById('country').value,
    currency: document.getElementById('currency').value,
    account_number: document.getElementById('account-number').value,
    account_holder_name: document.getElementById('account-holder-name').value,
    account_holder_type: document.getElementById('account-holder-type').value,
  }
  if (document.getElementById('routing-number').value != '') {
    bankAccountParams['routing_number'] = document.getElementById('routing-number').value;
  }

  stripe.createToken('bank_account', bankAccountParams).then(setOutcome);
});
```

Are you seeing anything that would be causing the token to not be created? There must be some interference happening here.

With navbar, no token is created.  Without it, it works fine.

Also, it's only when i take away the html code.  (in case that matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<nav> ... </nav>` block contains a `<form>` element, and when you use `document.querySelector('form')` to bind an event listener, it is binding to that form in your nav instead of the Stripe `<form>` element.

> querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Instead, you could try grabbing your payment form by id, like:

> document.getElementById('payment-form-1').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
>       ...
>       });

Comment: Looks like we're on the right direciton.  When I do "document.getElementById('payment-form-1').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {" ... the token is created but nothing actually submits to stripe.   I also tried : "document.querySelector('#payment-form-1').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {" when the same results

Comment: And to clarify, nothing happens aside from the token being shown on the page.  Nothing submits through, nothing loads or reloads, etc.

Comment: It danged doed worked.  Solved by also changing the var form to::: var form = document.getElementById('payment-form-1');

Comment: awesome, glad to hear it :)